# IOS: use a class to manage a simple game

Tags: ios, class, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing a simple game where you can choose if your game is "single player" or "multi player" (two player); 
The game is the same: in "one player mode" I should control the same things that I control with two player but two different times;
then I want to ask you if is a good idea use a third class, that manage my game, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes

**In general, it's always a good idea to compartmentalize your programs** (in any language!) as much as possible - this is what the whole Model-View-Controller paradigm is built off of.

In all of my apps, I always try to compartmentalize as much as possible. This might mean I have 50 source files, but they are all readable.

Comment: And what's the best way to do it? I make an example to you if I understand the concept; for example I create this third class Game (.h and .m), so in this class I have general methods that I can call from other classes right? (I created OnePlayer and TwoPlayer classes) For example I have a method in Game called "filterArray" that retur an array, in this way, in others classes I should import and alloc Game class, create and alloc my new array, and finally call the method to fill my new array...is this the concept?

Comment: @blackguardian Yep. That's the fundamental principle behind Objective-C. You generally have related methods grouped together in one class. For example, all of your game-array stuff might be in a class called MYArrayHelper.m/h.

Comment: Also, this increases the maintanability of your code - you only have to change stuff in one file instead of two or twenty-thousand.

Comment: This is why people go to university and those kinds of things. You should read a bit about Software Design and Software Patterns, that should help.

Comment: I think you should alloc Game class only once (singleton), in this class you create OnePlayer and TwoPlayer and pass a gameDelegate to them. So, for example, player1 hit player2, in OnePlayer class you call `[self.delegate addOnePlayerScore:1]`. The Game class behaves a game controller.

Comment: @blackguardian As @ djserva suggested, your example would probably be best implemented as a singleton. How this would work is you would alloc/init the class at startup in your AppDelegate, then would store the class in one of AppDelegate's properties. When you need it, you can get the delegate (google it), the acces the class through the property on the delegate.

Comment: can I follow thi tutorial? http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: @blackguardian Sure. There's not much that can go wrong. If you need more help, ask another question. Have I satisfactorily answered your question?

Comment: Yes I know how to use delegate in AppDelegate, I developed about 30 apps, but sometimes I want to improve my skills to have an optimized code...so I'm going to accept your answer, thanks so much